# Insert html linebreak in view output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a field in the database that has linebreaks in it.  I want to see the linebreaks in my view so I made this display template:

`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/_StringWithBreaks.cshtml`

```
@model string

@( Model.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br>") )
```

And then I call it like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BodyTemplate, "_StringWithBreaks" )
```

The problem is it escapes the HTML so instead of inserting in the HTML it escapes it so the `<br>` is readable.

What is the proper way to do this so breaks appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just style the containing element with  `white-space: pre` (a `DisplayTemplate` is not really necessary for this)

```
<div style="white-space: pre;">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BodyTemplate)
</div>
```

[css whitespace reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Thanks!.  `Pre` didn't wrap and `pre-wrap` inserted a load of space at start and end for some reason but `pre-line` was ideal, thanks.

Comment: If `pre-line` worked, then `pre` should (note its lower case). If `pre-wrap` was causing an issue, it suggests you might have a extra leading and trailing whitespace of tabs (you might want to use `.Trim()` before saving the value)

Comment: It's weird, there is no extra space in the database but there is white space at beginning and end of div in generated HTML, maybe asp.net indents it to make code look better?

Comment: Sure you do not have some other css adding padding or margins? (I cant duplicate what your claiming)

Comment: Sorry, I had the style attached to `<td>` tag.  I attached style to a `<div>` and the space disappeared.  I have Bootstrap CSS linked so that was probably to blame.